# FloatingActionButton! Why it does not work?

Tags: android, button, android-fragments, fragment, floating-action-button

```
  public class Advertisment extends Fragment  {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_advertisment, container, false);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT< Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            FloatingActionButton fab=(FloatingActionButton)v.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg){
                    Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), WriteAdvert.class);
                    startActivity(myIntent);
                }
            });
        }

}
```

I use a library https://github.com/shell-software/fab

This button should go to another activity but it does not.
I am a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the destination activity in your Android manifest.xml file ?

```
<application>
  <activity
        android:name="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MyActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.mycompany.myfirstapp.MyActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: http://prntscr.com/728q5u Your button is of type ActionButton, not FloatingActionButton (see link). Take a closer look at the github readme on how to call the button